# waiting for TT and H?

Tags: probability

We toss a fair coin until we see one consecutive TT pattern and one H, their order is irrelevant.

For instance, HHTHTHTT, or TTH.

Let X be the number of tossed required. What is E(X)?

Here is my solution: Let

$X_H$= number of tosses required to get H.

$X_{TT}$= number of tosses required to get TT.

First, note that $E(X_{TT})=6$. Then

$E(X)=\frac{1}{2}(2+6)+\frac{1}{4}(2+6)+\frac{1}{4}(2+2)=6.5$

Is it correct?

Comment: See here a related question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3149605/mean-number-of-attempts-for-3-events-to-happen/3149649#3149649

Answer (score 2):

Look at this flow chart (each arrow has probability $\frac{1}{2}$ except the last absorbing state has probility $1$ in its self-loop):

[image: flow chart for the problem]

Your answer $6.5$ is confirmed by calculating the expected number of steps for this [absorbing Markov chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorbing_Markov_chain) starting from the empty state and reaching the target state $(\text{has seen } H, TT)$.

It has $Q$-matrix

$$Q = \left[\begin{array}*
0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 &\frac{1}{2} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right]$$

Sum the first row of $(I-Q)^{-1}$ to get the answer:

$$1+\frac{1}{2} +\frac{1}{2}+3+\frac{3}{2} = \frac{13}{2}.$$

PS. I calculated the inverse with Wolfram Alpha with this input:

```
inverse ( 1/2*[[2,-1,0,-1,0], [0,2,-1,-1,0], [0,0,1,0,0], [0,0,0,1,-1], [0,0,0,-1,2]])
```